# Email Forwarding Server

Tags: web-hosting, email

We have a ton of websites on multiple different webhosts.

The way we have our email setup is we forward all of our email to gmail accounts (e.g. name@domain.com > whatever@gmail.com)

The problem is most of our webhosts now send a lot of legitimate email to Gmail's spam.

We're looking for a service that will only manage the emails (we don't want to switch webhosts as the actual hosting of the website is fine).  So we only want the emails to be managed, and all legitimate emails to be sent our way forwarded to our gmail accounts.

Any recommendations out there?

Comment: Could you explain more? Why do you wamt to manage emails, aren't you already managing them with your webhoster? Moreover why would you want to manage them differently, you are saying you still want to use them as simple forwarders.

Comment: I use them as forwarders at my existing webhost.

The existing webhost forwards the emails but about half of legitimate emails get filtered out as spam.

So I want to get a better email forwarding service without having to switch my entire websites onto a new host.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to avoid forwarding and use Gmail directly as your mail host with your own address, you need to **change your MX records**. The MX records tell your "old" host where to send your email.

Here's a how-to by Google: http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=33352&ctx=cb&src=cb&cbid=-hs9fd6sbkd5e&cbrank=2

**Note** that you can only send your emails to Google in this manner **if you have Google Apps** (I have done some research on this and have failed to find evidence to the contrary). You need to pay for Google Apps, though some webhosts like Weebly offer it for free for one website (about 40$ a year for ten users).

If you want to avoid sending your emails to your spam box, you can

- either configure Google to **get the emails by POP3** (you can do that in your Gmail settings) or
- **add your other email addresses to your contacts**. Whoever sends you an email and is in your contacts, will not be sent to spam